# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + \sin(\pi x)}{1 + \exp(\pi x)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + \sin(\pi x)}{1 + \exp(\pi x)} \,dx
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + \sin(\pi x)}{1 + e^{\pi x}} \,dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1 + e^{\pi x}} \,dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1 + e^{\pi x}} \,dx \\
&= \Omega_{1} + \Omega_{2}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\Omega_{1} &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1 + e^{\pi x}} \,dx \cdot \left\{e^{\pi x} = \frac{1}{t}, \, \pi x = -\ln(t), \, dx = -\frac{1}{\pi t}\right\} \\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(t)}{1 + \frac{1}{t}} \cdot \frac{1}{t} \,dt \\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(t)}{1 + t} \,dt \\
&= -\frac{1}{\pi^3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int_{0}^{1} t^n \ln^2(t) \,dt
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\text{cong} &= -\frac{2}{\pi^3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n + 1)^3} \\
&= \frac{3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^3}
\end{align*}

Comment: A minus-sign is missing in the last line.

Comment: Specifically, sign error comes from here: $= -\frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(t)}{1 + \frac{1}{t}} \cdot \frac{1}{t} \,dt $. The limits of integration actually transform to $\int_1^0$, so you have to flip them around. This cancels the minus sign from $dx/dt$. That said, what is the question here? Do you want this proof verified? Are you having trouble with $\Omega_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\Omega_2=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{1+e^x}dx
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{1+e^{-x}}dx
$$
the geometric series is
$$
=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\ge 0}(-)^k\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+1)x}\sin x dx
=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\ge 0}(-)^k \frac{1}{1+(k+1)^2}
$$
by partial fration composition,
with $i=\sqrt{-1}$, the imaginary unit
$$
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \frac{1}{2+2k+k^2}
= 
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(k+1-i)(k+1+i)}
= 
\frac{i}{2}\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k [\frac{1}{k+1+i}-\frac{1}{k+1-i}]
$$
$$
= 
\frac{i}{2}[\frac12 \psi(1+i/2)-\frac12 \psi(1/2+i/2)- \{\frac12 \psi(1-i/2)-\frac12 \psi(1/2-i/2)\}]
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{2}\Im [\frac12 \psi(1+i/2)-\frac12 \psi(1/2+i/2)- \frac12 \psi(1-i/2)+\frac12 \psi(1/2-i/2)]
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{2}[\Im \frac12 \psi(1+i/2)-\frac12 \frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- \Im \frac12 \psi(1-i/2)+\frac12 \frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{-\pi}{2}]
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{2}[\Im \frac12 \psi(1+i/2)-\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- \Im \frac12 \psi(1-i/2)]
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{4}[\Im \psi(1+i/2)-\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- \Im \psi(1-i/2)]
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{4}\{\Im [\psi(i/2)+\frac{1}{i/2}]-\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- \Im [\psi(-i/2)+\frac{-1}{i/2}]\}
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{4}\{\Im \psi(i/2)-2-\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- \Im \psi(-i/2)-2\}
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{4}\{\frac{1}{2\times 1/2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\coth\frac{\pi}{2}-2-\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}- (\frac{1}{2\times (-1/2)}+\frac{\pi}{2}\coth\frac{-\pi}{2}) -2\}
$$
$$
=
-\frac{1}{4}[-2-\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\coth\frac{\pi}{2}].
$$
$$
\Omega_2=\frac{1}{4\pi}[2+\pi\tanh \frac{\pi}{2}-\pi\coth \frac{\pi}{2}]
\approx 0.11586017\ldots
$$
For $\sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n/(1+n^2)$ see e.g. the Kotesovec formula of 2015 in https://oeis.org/A002522 .

Comment: Thanks alot (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Both of these integrals can be solved together pretty easily with geometric series. Consider

$$\frac{x^2+\sin\pi x}{1+e^{\pi x}} = \frac{(x^2+\sin\pi x)e^{-\pi x}}{1+e^{-\pi x}}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\pi x}(x^2+\sin\pi x)$$

The first integral is similar to how you computed it, just simpler without the intermediary substitution

$$\Omega_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-n\pi x}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi^3n^3}\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-t}dt$$

$$=\frac{2}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3} = \frac{2}{\pi^3}\left(-\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)\right)=-\frac{3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^3}$$

by recognizing the $2!$ and subtracting off twice the sum of the even terms. The second piece then is

$$\Omega_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^\infty\operatorname{Im}\{e^{(-n+i)\pi x}\}dx$$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Im}\left\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n-i}\right\} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2+1}$$

Comment: Thanks alot(+1)